# Am I able to query within a returned document with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like this...

```
var TerritorySchema = new Schema({
    user: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    streets: [streets_schema]
)};

var StreetsSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    odd: [block_schema],
    even: [block_schema],
    tags: [String]
)};
```

In need to be able to find a territory by a users id. However, I then need to find a street by name within the streets inside the returned document. This is how I'm doing it...

```
TerritoryModel.findOne({user: userId})
    .then(territory => {
        // now i have my territory parent object
        // and must find street by name
        var streetINeedToFind = null;
        for(i = 0; i < territory.streets.length; i++){
            var street = territory.streets[i];
            if(street.name === streetNameToFind){
                streetINeedToFind = street;
                break;
            }
         }
    })
    // catch blah blah blah ... you know
```

I am new to the NoSQL scene and I just feel like I should be able to query for the street I need, and have the database do all the searching for me.

The territory schema is actually a lot larger than what I defined above, and I am going to need to query for more deeply nested subdocuments (e.g house within a street etc). Is there a way to query within a document or some other easier way to uncover subdocuments, rather than looping through them?

I read up on aggregation but I'm not sure if that's what I need? I may be wrong, maybe what I'm doing is best practice, could someone please show me way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already queried for the full document, then you can directly use standard JS array methods like [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var streetINeedToFind = territory.streets.find(s => s.name === streetNameToFind);
```

However, if you only need specific parts of the document, then you can use the query projection techniques from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) to do that.

Comment: I opted for using standard JS methods, it works out better for me in the end because I am going to need access to the parent object to call the "save" method when I modify the subdocument.